# Problema em uma class de conexão

Tags: java

bom estou com esse error na minha class de conexão:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql///helpsemeq
```

não sei em qual parte errei no codigo:

```
package Conexao;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

import java.sql.SQLException;


public class ConnectionFactory {
    public Connection getConnection(){
        try{
        String nomeUsuario = "root";
        String senhaUsuario = "";
        String enderecoServidor = "localhost";
        String nomeBanco = "helpsemeq";
        return DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql//"+enderecoServidor+
                "/"+nomeBanco, nomeUsuario, senhaUsuario);

        } catch (SQLException ex){
            System.out.println("fail");
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Como está o seu classpath?

Comment: seria a  biblioteca do mysql?

Comment: Provavelmente sim.

Answer (score 0):

segue exemplo da minha classe de conexão mysql:
lembre de importar a biblioteca do mysql para seu projeto.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

/**
 * @author JCR
 *
 * Classe responsável pela conexão com o banco de dados MySQL
 *
 * Database: estoque User: root Password: ""
 *
 */
public class ConnectionFactoryMySQL {

    private static final String DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    private static final String URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/estoque";
    private static final String USER = "root";
    private static final String PASS = "";

    public static Connection getConnection() {
        try {
            Class.forName(DRIVER);
            return DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USER, PASS);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Erro na conexão MySQL", ex);
        }
    }

    public static void closeConnection(Connection con) {
        if (con != null) {
            try {
                con.close();
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                System.err.println("ERRO MySQL: " + ex);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void closeConnection(Connection con, PreparedStatement stmt) {
        if (stmt != null) {
            try {
                stmt.close();
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                System.err.println("ERRO MySQL: " + ex);
            }
        }
        closeConnection(con);
    }

    public static void closeConnection(Connection con, PreparedStatement stmt, ResultSet rs) {
        if (rs != null) {
            try {
                rs.close();
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                System.err.println("ERRO MySQL: " + ex);
            }
        }
        closeConnection(con, stmt);
    }
}
```